# making images appear in uniform sizes

Tags: html, css

In my website, I have a gallery which displays user uploaded images. The problem is , since we dont have a control over the dimensions of the images uploaded by the user, different images are appearing in different dimensions [image]. What is the best approach to make the images appear in uniform sizes using html? or is it best done in the jquery/javascript?

Comment: what do you mean by "uniform size"?

Comment: You mean you want to keep the propotions

Comment: You should probably resize the images server-side, and not in html, because otherwise people could upload very large images that everyone would have to download (which would be slow). This would also waste server bandwidth and storage.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to crop your images server-side but still want some level of uniformity then you could use the `max-width` and `max-height` properties in CSS and a small snippet of jQuery to do the job for you. This won't change the original image, but will shift it within it's container so it is centered but fills the frame.

You then need to decide the width and height that all thumbnails will be and they will overflow their boundaries centrally aligned and ultimately uniform.

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
 
 orientateGalleryImages($("#contentGallery").children().children().children("img")); 
 
});

function orientateGalleryImages(images) {
 
 images.each(function() {
  
  var thisImage = jQuery(this);
  
  if(thisImage.height() > thisImage.width()) {
   
   thisImage.addClass("portrait");
   
  } else if(thisImage.width() > thisImage.height()) {

   thisImage.addClass("landscape");

  } else {
   
   thisImage.addClass("square");       
  }      
 });     
}
```

```css
.galleryArea {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.galleryArea .imageWrapper {
 position: relative;
 width: 10%;
 padding-top: 10%;
 overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
.galleryArea .imagePosition {
 position: absolute;
 top: -50%;
 left: -50%; 
 width: 200%; 
 height: 200%;
}
.galleryArea .imagePosition img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
}
.galleryArea .imagePosition img.landscape {
 max-height: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
.galleryArea .imagePosition img.portrait {
 max-width: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
.galleryArea .imagePosition img.square {
 max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentGallery" class="galleryArea">
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x250">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x400">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x400">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x400">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x400">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="imageWrapper">
  <div class="imagePosition">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x300">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v6q426bp/10/)

---

#### HTML:

The HTML is a little long winded, but it is required to offset the image inside the parent.

#### JS:

The JavaScript looks at the longest edge of the image and adds a class to it of either Portrait, Landscape or Square. These classes specify either a `max-width`, `max-height` or both depending on the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is `wrap` all images in a 'div'.

HTML :

```
<div class="img_parent">
    <img />
</div>

<div class="img_parent">
    <img />
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.img_parent{ width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden; display:inline-block;}
.img_parent img{ width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this, is to give them fixed heights in css. (example `img{ height:100px; }` )

Comment: and `width:auto;` if you want to keep the proportions correct.

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

When users upload the images, make it automatically crop that image to a specific size eg. 400px x 400px

The demo below is just a crop idea, but you can modify the code to make it automatically crop it to a size of eg 400px x 400px

[Croppic example](http://www.croppic.net/)

This is just a thought. Hope you come right.